# Factorial does not work for all values

Tags: c++, function, factorial

Hi everyone I edited my post because I have another problem with my code.I had a problem with the factorial function yesterday but  I managed to solve it thanks to your answers , it was a ridiculous mistake.
The problem now is that for some values that are higher than 15, the final results(not the factorials of individual numbers) are always 0 or -1 for the lesser values it works fine.Can someone tell me whats wrong with this code :

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include<time.h>

    using namespace std;



    int factorial(int a){
    if(a==1)
      return 1;
    else if(a==0)
      return 1;
    else 
      return factorial(a-1)*a;

    }

    int main(){
    std::cout.setf(std::ios_base::fixed, std::ios_base::floatfield);
    std::cout.precision(5);
    int n,k;
    int x,y,z,w,v; 


    cout<<"give n : ";
    cin>>n;


     cout<<"give k : ";
     cin>>k;

     clock_t t;

        t = clock();



      if(n>=k&&k>1){

       x=factorial(n-1);
       y=factorial(k-1);
       z=factorial(n-1-k);
       w=factorial(n-k);
       v=factorial(k);


         cout<<"Result is "<<(x/(v*z))+(x/(y*w))<<endl;
       }
       else if (n==0||n==k)
         cout<<"Result is  1"<<endl;
       else
         cout<<"Result is  0"<<endl;


       t = clock() - t;
       cout<<"It took "<<t<<" clicks  ("<<((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<" seconds )"<<endl;    



       return 0;
       }
```

Comment: You'll need to show us the code for `factorial`.

Comment: Just a gotcha! - ensure when you're dividing, you do not run into a divide-by-zero error, i.e. the value for `v * z` and `y * w` should be non-zeroes. Posting the `factorial` function would give us more insight on what is going wrong.

Comment: Um, you didn't say where it crashes. When it crashes, use the debugger to see what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integer overflow.

If `int` is 32 bits on your system, the largest value it can represent is `2147483647`. 13 factorial is `6227020800`.

If you use a 64-bit integer type such a `long long`, you can go up to 20 factorial.

Floating-point will give you more range, but with a loss of precision.

If you really need to compute large factorials, you'll need to use some multi-precision library like [GMP](http://gmplib.org/), or use a language that has built-in arbitrary-precision integer arithmetic (C doesn't).

Comment: thanks for the answer  I will study a bit more on my own and see if I will change anything on my code.Since it is technically right though I don't think I will get penalised for not being able to compute all values

Answer (score 1):

The following might call `factorial` with a zero or negative argument:

```
z=factorial(n-1-k);
w=factorial(n-k);
```

You need to make sure that your `factorial` function can handle such arguments without crashing (I suspect it doesn't).

Comment: Thank you all I just realised I had forgot to calculate the factorial of zero in the factorial function.I didn t even care about looking at the function because I copy pasted from an old exercise which I considered until now correct