# How to fix stackoverflow exception in scala

Tags: scala

```
def factorial(n : Int) : Int = {
  if(n==1)
    1
  else
    n * factorial(n-1)
 }

println(factorial(500000))
```

While I am passing large value its throwing stackoverflow exception Can we fix it?

Comment: 500000! is very large number, it won't fit int 32-bit Int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question seems theoretical, because factorial of 500000 is really a huge number. The result is so huge it is not representable by [IEEE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) Double, and I doubt there is any practical reason why to compute it.

Some math calculators (like [SpeedCrunch](http://www.speedcrunch.org/)) let you compute factorial using the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), probably using some approximation for large numbers. The SpeedCrunch result of `gamma(500000 + 1)`is 1.02280158465190236533 * 10  <sup>2632341</sup>.

However, if you insist on doing it, this is how it can be done:

Implement factorial using tail recursion instead. See [Tail Recursion in Scala: A Simple Example](https://myadventuresincoding.wordpress.com/2010/06/20/tail-recursion-in-scala-a-simple-example/) or [http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-recursion-examples-recursive-programming](http://Simple%20Scala%20recursion%20examples%20(recursive%20programming))

Note: you will still get integer arithmetics overflow for large inputs, and the result will be wrong for them. The largest input for a 32b signed integer for which the result will still fit in a 32b signed result is 12 (cf. [Factorial does not work for all values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15189362/16673))

You can avoid this by using `Double` to compute the result (you will get approximate result only for large numbers, and Infinity for 500000) or by using `BigInt` - the calculation will work for all values, but it will get slower.

Following code should produce the correct result, but it might take very long, and the result will be very long - you might perhaps even get out of memory errors. I tried computing factorial of 50000 with it and it took several seconds, and the resulting number was several pages long.

```
def factorial(n: Long): BigInt = {
    @tailrec
    def factorialAccumulator(acc: BigInt, n: Long): BigInt = {
        if (n == 0) acc
        else factorialAccumulator(n*acc, n-1)
    }
    factorialAccumulator(1, n)
}
```

Comment: I have tried thsi- this is also working def factorial(n : Int, fact : BigInt) : BigInt = {
    if(n==1)
      fact
     else
      factorial(n-1, fact *n)
    }

println(factorial(50000,BigInt(1)))